# Select MySQL com 3 arrays

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela MySQL em que as entradas primárias são 3 colunas: ANO, NUMERO e PARCELA. 
A coluna NUMERO é uma numeração sequencial para cada ANO, porém é possível que para um mesmo número haja diversas PARCELAS.
Preciso realizar um SELECT com arrays, onde tenho um array para ANO, outro para NUMERO e outro para PARCELA.
O fato é que se utilizo "IN", ele não traz o número associado ao ANO e a PARCELA.
Por exemplo:

```
ANO NUMERO PARCELA
17  5673   1
17  6783   1
18  5673   1
18  6790   1
```

E crio as seguintes entradas $ano = ('17', '18'), $numero = ('5673', '6790') e $parc = ('1', '1'), ao realizar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ANO IN($ano) AND NUM IN($numero) AND PARC IN($parc)
```

O resultado será:

```
17 -> 5673 -> 1
18 -> 5673 -> 1
18 -> 6790 -> 1
```

Sendo que o que desejo é:

```
17 -> 5673 -> 1
18 -> 5673 -> 1   <---- SEM ESSE RESULTADO
18 -> 6790 -> 1
```

Ou seja, quero que cada entrada da "array" $ano esteja associada à entrada do "array" $numero, associada à entrada da "array" $parc.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que deseja. O que você quer dizer em `cada entrada da "array"` ? Você diz que precisa que traga na ordem que está em `$ano = ('17', '18'), $numero = ('5673', '6790') e $parc = ('1', '1')` ? Ou seja, 17 - 5673 - 1 e 18 - 6790 - 1 ? Caso for isso, está errado utilizar o IN. Se você tem um `array`, faça o loop nele filtrando 1 a 1. Isso `$ano = ('17', '18')` não é um array. Seria `$ano = array('17', '18')`, e aí sim poderia fazer o `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente você está querendo que cada correspondência de coluna **A** dentro do conjunto **X** esteja na mesma posição no conjunto que a correspondência da próxima coluna **B** no outro conjunto **Y**.

No SQL não há como você expressar isso, então eu partiria de uma abordagem diferente.

O dado que você quer usar como filtro, na verdade é a combinação dos valores de ano, numero e parcela. Ou seja, de acordo com seu exemplo, uma combinação seria `17 + 5670 + 1` e a outra `18 + 6790 + 1`.

Obviamente tratariamos essas informações como texto para evitar coincidências na soma e eu adicionaria também um caractere separador entre os dados.

Para não deteriorar tanto a performance da consulta no banco, eu também manteria os filtros `IN` nas colunas isoladas somente com os valores distintos para cada campo. No final, sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE  t.ano IN ( 17,18 ) AND 
   t.numero IN ( 5673, 6790 ) AND
   t.parcela IN ( 1 ) AND 
   Concat( t.ano, '#', t.numero, '#', t.parcela ) IN ( '17#5673#1', '18#6790#1' )
```

[Veja esse exemplo funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bce5/9).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Show de bola Diego, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @RafaelSchafferGimenes É uma solução de contorno (_gambiarra_) de melhor esforço, eu acredito que resolve o seu problema. Não é uma ótima solução porque esse tipo de problema deveria ser resolvido na modelagem em si. (y) Precisando de ajuda, estamos aí.